# How to write stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblSingleQuery]
(
    Id Int IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProdId INT,
    ColorId INT,
    IsFront BIT DEFAULT 0
)
```

[image]

I want to create a stored procedure with input parameter `@ColorId` which will fetch the results using a `where` clause `ColorId <> @ColorId`. But when I pass `@ColorId = 0` then it should exclude records having `IsFront = 1`.

Currently I have created the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_GetProductColorImage]
    @ColorId INT
AS
BEGIN
   IF @ColorId = 0
   BEGIN
       SELECT * 
       FROM [tblSingleQuery] 
       WHERE IsFront <> 1
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
       SELECT * 
       FROM [tblSingleQuery] 
       WHERE ColorId <> @ColorId 
   END
END
```

How can I manage this in a single select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM [tblSingleQuery] 
WHERE
    (@ColorId = 0 AND IsFront <> 1 ) OR 
    (@ColorId != 0 AND ColorId <> @ColorId )
```